# Adding Search Block to Bootstrap 3 Navbar

Tags: theming, blocks, search

The search block using the twitter [bootstrap 3 theme](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) doesn't show inline with the rest of the navbar. What is the trick to get this to show inline?

I have tried to add it to the page.tpl.php without success.

Any ideas?

EDIT:::

I've added this to the template:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
           <?php if (!empty($page['searchblock'])): ?>
            <?php print render($page['searchblock']); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
```

However, that doesn't seem exactly right for this bootstrap theme. In the bootstrap code one wraps the search like so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Do I need to modify the default search block template? Thanks for any help to my ignorance as i learn this system. Really digging Drupal 7 right now!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same feature request.
In `mytheme/template.php` I've added

```
/*
 *  Preprocess page.tpl.php to inject the $search_box variable.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $search_form = drupal_get_form('search_form');
  $search_box = drupal_render($search_form);
  $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}

/*
 *  Form alter to add missing bootstrap classes and role to search form.
 */
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'navbar-form';
    $form['#attributes']['role'][] = 'search';
  }
}
```

In `mytheme/templates/page.tpl.php` I've added

```
<div class="col-md-3 nav nabvar-nav navbar-right">
  <?php print $search_box; ?>
</div>
```

After the

```
<div class="navbar-header"> div.
```

There still was a problem with a float:left applied to secondary links menu (instead of the proper boostrap navbar-right.
So, for a quick workaround, in `mytheme/css/style.css` I've added:

```
@media(max-width:768px){
  ul.secondary{
    float:none!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange thing about this is when I add anything to my template.php I get a blank page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jasonflaherty I have never had that problem, but I would check a couple of things mentioned in the [Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD)](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) page, specifically "Character Encoding on template.php" and the directory (sites/all or sites/default) related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something along these lines:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
        <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your tag, you're looking for a D7 solution. The Drupal 7 page.tpl.php doesn't have the $search_box variable anymore. However you can add it in a preprocess function in your template.php:

```
<?php
/*
 *  Preprocess page.tpl.php to inject the $search_box variable back into D7.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $search_box = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_form'));
  $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}
```

Then you just need to print the variable in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $search_box; ?>
```

You could also use module_invoke, but you shouldn't have php logic in template files:

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
  print render($block); 
?>
```

Answer originally posted https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/10288

Answer (score 0):

According to the bootstrap module page about this issue ( [search block in navbar strange behaviour](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113693) ), the best solution to date is the following css rule :

```
#search-block-form .input-group-btn {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it following the comment of Chris Godwin in page.tpl.php:

> ```
> <?php if (!empty($primary_nav) || !empty($secondary_nav) || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
>   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
>     <nav role="navigation">
>       <?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
>         <?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
>       <?php endif; ?>
>         <div class="col-md-3 nav nabvar-nav navbar-right">
>             <?php print $search_box; ?>
>         </div>
>       <?php if (!empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
>         <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
>       <?php endif; ?>
>     </nav>
>   </div>
> <?php endif; ?>
> ```